# Stopping Azure Waagent

Tags: azure

I have created a Linux VM with waagent service in it on Azure using ARM. But I want to restrict the creation of any user from Azure UI. I could not get any option to do so.

I was thinking of stopping WAagent service which will disconnect VM with Azure UI layer. are there any issues which I can face by disabling the service inside the VM ?

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to restrict the creation of any user from Azure UI

Do you mean you want to limit users to create Azure VM?

Maybe you can use [RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) to manage permission, in this way, you can limit Azure users to create Azure VM.

> are there any issues which I can face by disabling the service inside
> the VM ?

If your VM is running, after you disable the waagent, you still can connect to your VM, but if there something wrong with your VM, you will lost control of that VM, you can't use Waagent to manage your VM.

Azure does **not** recommend to disable Waagent.

### Update

If you are the administrator of that subscription, you can remove other roles in access control:

[image]

You can just give them reader role, in this way, they can't reset your VM's password.

Comment: But I want to restrict the creation of any user from Azure UI:
I mean that Azure allows to reset password for existing user from UI and if the user does not exist, it creates. But I don't want that any user should reset password or create other user once configured at boot time. It is kind of special VM. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: @GouravSingla Does this VM created in one resource group? or multiple VMs created in the same resource group?

Comment: @GouravSingla I have update my answer, please check it